# parse text file using multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, string-parsing

I'm new to python programming. I want to split a text file that has two delimiters.

I'm just hard coding one line of the text file to get the logic right. I want to print the delimiter after splitting the text. Not quite sure on how to do it.

```
  text='+1  This book is awesome.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends.  -1    I bought this for my sister and she didn't like it. The note sections to t'
   for line in text.split('+1'):
      print line
```

This give me the output without +1, but i want the output like this:

```
+1  This book is awesome.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends.
-1  I bought this for my sister and she didn't like it. The note sections to t
```

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `find` method of strings: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.find

*After* you understand what it's doing, use `text.find("+1")` and `text.find("-1")`.

Also: `split` does not work the way you think it does. Read the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.split), run `"ab ac bc de".split("ab")`, look at the result and make sure you understand what's happening.